# Django: date format management and unique_together -> "20/03/2020" value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.”]

Tags: javascript, python, django, date

I develop a Django project with internationalization English/French

dates have to be displayed with the dd/mm/yyyy format when user webbrowser is FR and yyyy-mm-dd when user webbrowser is EN

to do that, I use JS that test webbrowser user favorite language and display format accordingly

That works fine until I change my model to add **unique_together** constraint with this date

Now, I got the error when webbrowser is in french and I try to register date (**asp_ent_dat**)

```
 'date format "20/03/2020" is invalid. Correct format is "yyy-mm-dd".
```

**models.py:**

```
class Entree(models.Model):

    asp_ent_cle = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    asp_ent_loc = models.CharField("Site concerned by the operation", max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    med_num = models.CharField("Trial batch number", max_length=3, null=True, blank=True,)
    asp_ent_dat = models.DateField("Entry date", null=True, blank=True)
    asp_ent_pro_pay = models.CharField("Country of treatment origin in case of entry", max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    asp_ent_pro_sit = models.CharField("Processing source site in case of entry", max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    opr_nom = models.CharField("Input operator", max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    opr_dat = models.DateField("Entry date", null=True, blank=True)
    log = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:

        db_table = 'pha_asp_ent'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Entries'
        ordering = ['asp_ent_cle']
        unique_together = ['asp_ent_loc','med_num','asp_ent_dat']
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){

    if(window.navigator.language == 'fr-FR' | window.navigator.language == 'fr'){
        $("#id_asp_ent_dat").datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            }
        );
    } 
    else
    {
        $("#id_asp_ent_dat").datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            }
        );
});
```

**forms.py:**

```
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(EditForm, self).clean()
        cle1 = self.data.get('asp_ent_loc')
        cle2 = self.data.get('med_num')
        # cle3 = self.data.get('asp_ent_dat')    ***LINE THAT RAISE ERROR***
        cle3 = self.cleaned_data['asp_ent_dat']
```

Answer (score 2):

Add valid Date formats to `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`.

[`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-input-formats)

Comment: thank for replying I add DATE_INPUT_FORMATS ['%Y-%m-%d', '%d/%m/%Y',] but still have the error

Comment: 20/03/2020 ('%d/%m/%Y') is not the list of format that seems to be authorized in the documentation

Comment: I test it out. It's working for me. What `datepicker` are you using?

Comment: JQuery datepicker

Comment: Did you added it to your `settings.py`?

Comment: what do you mean? adding JQuery datepicker to Settings.py?

Comment: Did you add `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` to your `settings.py`?

Comment: I try to implement this solution but also failed: https://joshuahunter.com/posts/formatting-date-fields-in-django/

Comment: finally, the problem came from another validation line in forms.py: cf EDIT